# how to display an array content inside CKeditor?

Tags: php, ckeditor

I need to display the content of doc file inside CKeditor.
I read the content of doc file & passing it into an array line by line :

```
$rs = fopen("text.doc", "r");

            while ($line = fgets($rs, 1024)) {
                $this->data[] = $line . "<BR>";
            }
```

then I create an instance of CKeditor:

```
include_once("ckeditor/ckeditor.php");
    $CKeditor = new CKeditor();
    $CKeditor->basePath = '/ckeditor/';
    foreach ($this->data as $value) {
                 //what should I write here
    }
    $CKeditor->editor('editor1');
```

the CKeditor work right now & appear on my webpage .. but without any content ?
what should I right inside the foreach to passing array content into the editor ?
please help =(

Answer (score 1):

`.doc` files are zipped up and cannot be read like this, by line. Consider using [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) to get access to the contents inside.

EDIT: Looks like PHPDoc can only write and not read, upon further investigation.

PHP tools are very deficient in this area. Your best bet is to use something like [DocVert](http://holloway.co.nz/docvert/faq.html) to do your file conversions on the command line. THEN you could load that document inside CKEditor.

EDIT: after OP's comment:

> let's consider it's a txt file ... I need the Ckeditor method

Load your decoded HTML content into a Textarea, and give this textarea an HTML ID or class:
`$textarea_content = htmlspecialchars_decode(file_get_contents('text.doc'));`

Then, in your HTML, call the CKEditor inside a JavaScript tag to replace the textarea with the editor:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- include CKEditor in a <script> tag first -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="editor1" name="editor1"><?php echo $textarea_content ?></textarea>
</body>
```

The [documentation page](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration) has a lot more details.

Comment: the problem isn't doc file the problem is how to passing array

Comment: You don't seem to understand. PHP cannot read that .doc file natively. It is not a simple text file. 'Passing the array' is the least of your problems here.

Comment: let's consider it's a txt file ... I need the Ckeditor method